# Default value of parameter is not used in function

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a very basic PowerShell script:

```
Param(
    [string]$MyWord
)

function myfunc([string] $MyWord) {
    Write-Host "$MyWord"
}
myfunc @PSBoundParameters
```

This is how I execute it:

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -MyWord 'hello'
hello
```

All fine. But I want to set a default value if `-MyWord` isn't specified.
I tried this:

```
Param(
    [string]$MyWord='hi'
)

function myfunc([string] $MyWord) {
    Write-Host "$MyWord"
}
myfunc @PSBoundParameters
```

But than the output of my script was just empty. It was printing nothing when I did not describe my parameter. (it only showed 'hello' if I specified the parameter). 
I also tried:

```
Param(
    [string]$MyWord
)

function myfunc([string] $MyWord) {
    [string]$MyWord='hi'
    Write-Host "$MyWord" 
}
myfunc @PSBoundParameters
```

But than the output was of course always 'hi' and never 'hello'. Even when I executed the script with the parameter `-MyWord 'hello'`

Can someone explaining what I'm doing wrong?

When I'm not using the function it is working as expected:

```
Param(
    [string]$MyWord='hi'
)
Write-Host $MyWord
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -MyWord 'hallo'
hallo

PS C:\> .\test.ps1
hi
```

Comment: It's an interesting question; perhaps you could make it clearer by prefacing it with your intent (assuming I'm reading it correctly): You want your _script_ to _pass through_ to your _function_ all parameters that have a value,
including parameters with _default values_. (The latter are, unfortunately, not reflected in `$PSBoundParameters`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automatic variable **`$PSBoundParameters`**, as the name suggests, contains only *bound* parameters, where ***bound* means that an actual value was supplied by *the caller***.

Therefore, a parameter ***default value* does *not* qualify as *binding*** the associated parameter, so `$MyWord` with its default value of `'hi'` does *not* become part of `$PSBoundParameters`.

**Note**: Arguably, a parameter with a default value should also be considered bound (it is bound by its *default value*, as opposed to by a caller-supplied value). Either way, **it would be convenient to have an automatic variable that includes default values too, so as to enable simple and comprehensive passing through of arguments**. A suggestion has been submitted to the PowerShell repository [as GitHub issue #3285](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285).

---

#### Workarounds

- The following solutions assume that you want to **pass the default value *through***, and don't want to simply *duplicate* the default value in function `myfunc` (as demonstrated in [Ansgar Wiecher's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677597/45375)), because that creates a maintenance burden.
- Regarding **function *syntax***: The following two forms are *equivalent* (in this case), though you may prefer the latter for consistency and readability.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - `function myfunc([string] $MyWord = 'hi') { ... }`
    parameter declaration inside *`(...)` after the function name*.
  - `function myfunc { param([string] $MyWord = 'hi') ... }`
    parameter declaration inside a `param(...)` block *inside the function body*.

---

A **simple fix** would be to add the default value explicitly to `$PSBoundParameters`:

```bash
Param(
     [string]$MyWord = 'hi'
)

function myfunc ([string] $MyWord){
    Write-Host "$MyWord" 
}

# Add the $MyWord default value to PSBoundParameters.
# If $MyWord was actually bound, this is effectively a no-op.
$PSBoundParameters.MyWord = $MyWord

myfunc @PSBoundParameters
```

---

To **achieve what you want *generically*,** you must use reflection (introspection):

```bash
param(
  [alias('foop')]
  [string]$MyWord = 'hi'
)

function myfunc ([string] $MyWord) {
  Write-Host "$MyWord" 
}

# Add all unbound parameters that have default values.
foreach ($paramName in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys) {
  if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($paramName)) {
    $defaultVal = Get-Variable -Scope Local $paramName -ValueOnly
    # A default value is identified by either being non-$null or
    # by being a [switch] parameter that defaults to $true (which is bad practice).
    if (-not ($null -eq $defaultVal -or ($defaultVal -is [switch] -and -not $defaultVal))) {
      $PSBoundParameters[$paramName] = $defaultVal
    }
  }
}

myfunc @PSBoundParameters
```

---

<sup>[1] The `param(...)` form is *required* if you need to use the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute with non-default values, as well as in *scripts* (`.ps1`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946390/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A parameter is bound only if you actually pass it a value, meaning that a parameter's default value does not show up in `$PSBoundParameters`. If you want to pass script parameters into a function, you must replicate the script parameter set in the function parameter set:

```
Param(
    [string]$MyWord = 'hi'
)

function myfunc([string]$MyWord = 'hi') {
    Write-Host "$MyWord" 
}

myfunc @PSBoundParameters
```

Maintaining something like this is easier if you define both parameter sets the same way, though, so I'd put the function parameter definition in a `Param()` block as well:

```
Param(
    [string]$MyWord = 'hi'
)

function myfunc {
    Param(
        [string]$MyWord = 'hi'
    )

    Write-Host "$MyWord" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "**Param**" enclose it in the function like this:

```
function myfunc {

    Param(
        [string]$MyWord='hi'
    )

    Write-Host "$MyWord" 
}
```

Comment: `param(...)` is being used correctly by the OP to declare parameter for the _script_. Inside a function, you get to _choose_ between the `param(...)` syntax, as in your answer, and the `myfunc([string] $MyWord)` variant chosen by the OP - makes no difference. _Duplicating_ the _script's_ default value for `$MyWord` inside the function is, I think, exactly what the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way is,

```
function myfunc([string]$MyWord = "hi") {
Write-Output $MyWord
}
```

Comment: The question is about passing the _script's_ default value through to the _function_, without needing to duplicate the default value in the function. But, yes, this is how you can define a default value for the function.