# In powershell is there a difference between having param in a function or putting parameters in the function?

Tags: powershell

In powershell you can make functions with `function name {commands}` and make those functions take arguments with this:

```
function myFunction {
    param($var1, $var2)
}
```

but you can also accomplish this with

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2) {}
```

and they would be the same.

For example, if I made a function `func1` be:

```
function func1 {
    param($var1, $var2)
    echo "$var1 $var2"
}
```

I would call it by using `func1 1 2` where `$var1` would be equal to `1` and `$var2` would be equal to `2`.

Input:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> func1 1 2
```

Output:

```
1 2
```

However, if I do the same thing but instead I did the other method of passing arguments to functions:

```
function func2($var1, $var2) {
    echo "$var1 $var2"
}
```

I would also call it the same exact way, calling it by using `func2 1 2` where `$var1` would be equal to `1` and `$var2` would be equal to `2` like the previous function.

Input:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> func2 1 2
```

Output:

```
1 2
```

So everything seems the same and constant between the two renditions of the function, so my question is, **is there a difference between the two methods of passing arguments to functions or are they both actually the same?** Even if it is the most minor of details, or just a parsing difference, I would like to know any differences between the two *in functions specifically* since param has other uses as well.

**UPDATE**: The arguments you can do in `param` like `[parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]` and `[String[]]` are not unique to param. You can also accomplish this in the other 'non-param' example by doing:

```
function func2(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, etc)] 
    [String[]]
    $var1, $var2
) {
    echo "$var1 $var2" 
}
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a difference. Please note that when calling the function, do _not_ use parentheses and commas.  You should call the function like: "func1 1 2"  If you use "func1(1,2)", the parentheses are parsed as an array initializer with two elements, and this array is passed to $var1. Note for clarity you could also call like this "func1 -var1 1 -var2 2"

Comment: It seems that there is far less documentation on the non-param alternative for passing arguments to functions, is param a more true-powershell solution?

Comment: I think it's an issue of style. With Param, it seems to be clearer to write longer parameter lists with attributes, default values, etc. Can do the same in the inline-list but I think it's just a legacy style thing.

Comment: And by the way func(1)(2) is legal but very unusual looking. Parentheses either specify ordering, compute a result or initialize an array. PowerShell calls typically expect spaces between arguments, which may have their names prepended like func -var1 1 -var2 2, or optional like func 1 2. I know it's weird looking especially coming from pretty much any other language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing is that the `CmdletBinding` attribute requires `Param`

```bsh
function Echo-Confirm
{
    # Here
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact="High")]
    Param ($val=1)

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($val) -eq $true) {
        Write-Output "Confirmed $val"
    }
}
```

---

Edit after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944141/in-powershell-is-there-a-difference-between-having-param-in-a-function-or-puttin/61952581?noredirect=1#comment109621767_61952581)

The syntax is fine, but `CmdletBinding` has no effect

```bsh
Function foo (
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact="High")]
    [Parameter()]$val=1
) {
    # never confirm
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($val) -eq $true) {
        Write-Output "always here"
    }
    else {
       Write-Output "never here"
    }
}


foo -Confirm
# throws an error
foo: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'confirm'.
```

Answer (score 10):

To complement [7cc's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952581/45375):

While the **two syntax forms are *mostly* interchangeable** when you define a *function*'s parameters, **only the `param(...)` block syntax works in the following circumstances**:

- If you want to use a **`[CmdletBinding()]`** attribute and its properties to (explicitly) make your function or script an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) or script.<sup>[1]</sup>
- If you're writing a **script file**(`*.ps1`) or **script block** (`{ ... }`): the only way to declare parameters for them is is by placing a `param(...)` block at the beginning.

Therefore, **you may opt to *always* use the `param(...)` block syntax, for consistency** across function and script parameter definitions.

If a [`[CmdletBinding(...)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute))  attribute is used, it must directly precede the `param(...)` block.

---

As for:

> I would call it by using `func1(1)(2)`

No, you would call it as follows:

```
func1 1 2
```

That is, PowerShell functions are called like *shell commands*: without parentheses, separated by whitespace; while your invocation happens to work too, the use of `(...)` around the arguments can change their interpretation:

- *without* the enclosing `(...)` the arguments are parsed in *argument* mode, where, notably, strings needn't be quoted
- *with* the enclosing `(...)`, are parsed in *expression* mode, where strings do need to be quoted.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] While you can place a `[CmdletBinding(...)]` attribute inside the parentheses with the `function Foo (...) { ... }` syntax without provoking an error, doing so is *effectively ignored*. Separately, in the absence of an (effective) *explicit* `[CmdletBinding(...)]` attribute, with *either* syntax, if you happen to decorate at least one parameter with a `[Parameter()]` attribute, you get the *default* behaviors of an advanced function (e.g., support for automatic common parameters such as `-Verbose`), because using `[Parameter()]` *implicitly* makes a function an advanced one (as if a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute - without explicit property values - were in effect). However, if you need an explicit `[CmdletBinding(...)]` attribute, so as to opt into *non-default* advanced-function behaviors, via property values such as `PositionalBinding=$false` or `SupportsShouldProcess=$true`, use of a `param(...)` block is your only option.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

From [About Functions - Functions with Parameters - Named Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7#named-parameters):

> You can define any number of named parameters. You can include a
>   default value for named parameters, as described later in this topic.
>
> *You can define parameters inside the braces using the `Param` keyword*,
>   as shown in the following sample syntax:
>
> ```
> function <name> {
>   param ([type]$parameter1[,[type]$parameter2])
>   <statement list>
> }
> ```
>
> *You can also define parameters outside the braces without the `Param`
>   keyword*, as shown in the following sample syntax:
>
> ```
> function <name> [([type]$parameter1[,[type]$parameter2])] {
>   <statement list>
> }
> ```
>
> …
>
> While the first method is preferred, **there is no difference between
>   these two methods**.

**Edit**

1. @mklement0 thanks for [helpful explication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946390/3439404) of the latter (emphasized) statement.
2. This statement (*there is no difference between these two methods*) **is valid** despite of [7cc's improper guesswork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952581/3439404).
3. [**7cc's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952581/3439404) **is right**, explained in mklement0's comments below and his updated answer.

In [About Functions Advanced Parameters => Attributes of parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7#attributes-of-parameters), there are some allusions to the relation of **CmdletBinding** and **Parameter** attributes and **advanced functions** (*advanced functions use the CmdletBinding attribute to identify them as functions that act similar to cmdlets*):

> … if you omit the **CmdletBinding** attribute, then to be recognized
>   as an *advanced function*, the function must include the **Parameter**
>   attribute…
>
> … to be recognized as an *advanced function*, rather than a simple
>   function, a function must have either the **CmdletBinding** attribute
>   or the **Parameter** attribute, or both.

I can't comprehend PowerShell inventors' motivation for such (confusing for me) design…

Comment: It's just putting some attribute like `[CmdletBinding()]$foo = 1`, which does nothing.
`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess` never works.

Comment: @7cc is correct: While you can place a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute inside the parentheses with the `function Foo (....)` syntax, it is _effectively ignored_. Separately, if you happen to decorate at least one parameter with a `[Parameter()]` attribute, you get the _default_ behaviors of an advanced functions (e.g, support for automatic common parameters such as `-Verbose`), because using `[Parameter()]` _implicitly_ makes a function an advanced one (it's like an implied, `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute, without property values). However, any _explicit_ use of `CmdletBinding` is ignored.

Comment: To put it differently: use of at least one `[Parameter()]` attribute alone (with either syntax form) implicitly gives you the _default_ behaviors of an advanced function. If you need non-default behaviors, such as `PositionalBinding=$false`, or `SupportsShouldProcess=$true`, your only option is to use the `param(...)` syntax.