# How can I pass multiple values to a PowerShell function that accepts an array of input objects?

Tags: powershell, function, pipeline

How can I pass values to my functions in the same way the PowerShell cmdlet `Write-Output` can be passed multiple values and process them as expected?

```
'one', 'two' | Write-Output
```

which will product the following output

```
one
two
```

I thought this was a way to do that, but it isn't:

```
Function ProcessNames ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$Names) {
  Foreach ( $name in $Names ) {
    # do something
  }
}
'bob', 'alice' | ProcessNames
```

In the above example, only the last element in the list gets processed - in this case 'alice'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have built your function in the simplified style. Functions have a `BEGIN`, `PROCESS`, and `END` block, of which only the `END` block runs by default. You can fix it by declaring that you want to operate in the `PROCESS` scriptblock like this:

```
Function ProcessNames ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$Names) {
  PROCESS{
      Foreach ( $name in $Names ) {
        $name
      }
  }
}
'bob', 'alice' | ProcessNames
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [TheMadTechnician's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76963087/45375):

- In addition to using a `process` block, it's better to also use a `param(...)` block for parameter declarations in [advanced functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) - which your function *implicitly* is, due to use of a `[Parameter()]` attribute.

  - Only a `param(...)` block allows you to use the [`[CmdletBinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute) attribute, which modifies the behavior of advanced functions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946390/45375).
- If your intent is to support processing multiple input objects *via the pipeline only*, you needn't declare your pipeline-binding parameter *as an array*.

  - In fact, the majority of cmdlets work this way - they do *not* meaningfully support processing an *array* of input objects passed to the pipeline-binding parameter *directly*, as an *argument* - see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) for a discussion.
  - That said, [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) are notable exceptions; e.g., the following commands are equivalent to providing `1, 2, 3` via the pipeline:
    `Write-Output -InputObject 1, 2, 3`
    `Out-File out.txt -InputObject 1, 2, 3`
    `Set-Content out.txt -Value 1, 2, 3`

---

**Supporting multiple input objects *via the pipeline only*** simplifies - and speeds up - things:

```bash
function ProcessNames {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string] $Name # Defined as a *single* string
  ) 
  process {
    # Do something with $Name
    $Name + '!' # sample operation
  }
}
```

`'bob', 'alice' | ProcessNames` then yields the equivalent of: `'bob!', 'alice!'`

---

**If pipeline input is *all* you need to support - not also *arguments*** - a simple alternative is to use a **[`filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#filters)**, which is a simplified version of a `function` that (a) has *no parameters* and (b) whose body implicitly runs inside a `process` block and receives pipeline input via [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) (aka `$PSItem`):

```bash
filter ProcessNames {
  # Do something with $_
  $_ + '!' # sample operation
}
```